# Working With 4 textfields and id sender 10 buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i`m trying to figure out what if i have 4 textfields field1,field2,field3 and field4, and 10 buttons tagged from 0 to 9, and when i press on a button it will show its tag number on the SELECTED textfield

my code for the 10 buttons is

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
field1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f",currentNumber];
}
```

this will only send the tag to field1.

i have 4 fields and i want the button to send the tag to the selected field.

is it possible ? if its can you please explain it to me ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Doesn't sound like anything you are trying to do is impossible, but I would like to know more.  I don't completely understand how 10 buttons map to 4 text fields!!!

Comment: its a calculator , the 10 buttons are linked to the same action

Comment: OK, so each button is one of the numbers 0 - 9, but you say you want the selected field to receive the number.  Are the 4 fields because you only accept four digit numbers, or what?  if you knew which was selected, you could simply have a UITextField * selectedField pointer and set that pointer to the proper field when the user selected it, then you could put the number to that field just by calling a different variable.

Comment: you are right , how can i do it ? can u please explain it ? @trumpetlicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a global

```
UITextField * selectedField;
```

When a user selects the field

```
selectedField = field1
or
selectedField = field2
or
selectedField = field3
or
selectedField = field4
```

Then you could implement your

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    currentNumber = [selectedField.text floatValue];
    currentNumber += (float)[sender tag];
    selectedField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f",currentNumber];
}
```

If may be easier (and may hold the right number better) to manipulate your input as a string rather than converting it to the numeric , then adding value, then re-converting back to string though!!!  I think you're going to find doing it the way you are, than you will run into floating point conversion problems going back and forth the way you are!!!

This way you are always setting the text to the selected field

Comment: Each UITextField needs to have a way of being selected, I would do this with an action, so that when the user taps the field, it becomes the selected field.  If you do this though, you are going to have to deal with the natural keyboard coming up, to allow your buttons to be the relevant input method.

Comment: No problem, glad I could at least get you started!

Answer (score 0):

i found it

it was very easy :)

```
if ([field1 isFirstResponder])
```

that would solve the problem :)

Comment: You have accepted an answer *and* posted your own answer. You should probably accept this answer instead of the other one if this is really what solved your problem.